# How to remove extra white pace along with "-" from a variable

Tags: shell

I have a variable

```
sha=10d212d1abec0222ac00f2dd728ef98de7e4a36e5f0832ccb445f15697ce0419 -
```

My question is How to remove extra white space along with - from that variable

Using shell commands How to do that?

Actual:

```
  10d212d1abec0222ac00f2dd728ef98de7e4a36e5f0832ccb445f15697ce0419 -
```

Expected:

```
  10d212d1abec0222ac00f2dd728ef98de7e4a36e5f0832ccb445f15697ce0419
```

Comment: You can use `sed` with `echo` : `sha="$(echo "$sha" | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]-]*//')"`

Comment: echo "Email id :" $email
sha=$(echo -n "$email" | shasum -a 256)
echo " Email in SHA256 Format:"$sha
v="$(echo "$sha" | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]-]*//')"    But not getting required result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sha=$(echo a b-c |tr -d '[[:blank:]]-')
```

Seee *man tr* for details.

Note that this deletes all whitespace from `sha`, not only at the end.